# how to compress a folder without to leave the original folder and without to remove the original folder

Tags: linux, tar, gzip, cpio

under SQL directory we have only the tmp folder (tmp folder usage 59G)

is it possible to compress the folder tmp without to leave the original tmp folder ?  , so the compression will work on the original folder

the folder usage:

```
 root@serverE1:/var/backup/SQL #  du -sh *

 59G     tmp
```

so after compression I will see only this :  (8G is only example)

```
 8G   tmp.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems to solve:

- how to remove the files without interfering with your output, and
- where to put the output while it is being created.

If you happen to not have any dot-files in `/var/backup/SQL`, it is simple:

- just create your output named with a leading ".",
- add to the tar-file using the `--remove-files` option, and
- rename the output to `tmp.tar.gz` when done.

Something like

```
cd /var/backup/SQL
tar cfz .tmp.tar.gz --remove-files * && mv .tmp.tar.gz tmp.tar.gz
```

If you *do* have dot-files, then you could construct a list of the files to be tar'd and then use that list in constructing the tar-file.  Using Linux, you could use the `-T` (`--files-from`) option to read this list, e.g.,

```
cd /var/backup/SQL
find . -type f >/tmp/list
tar czf tmp.tar.gz --remove-files --files-from /tmp/list
```

(Someone's sure to suggest process substitution rather than a temporary file, but that has the drawback of limited size, which may be a problem).

Answer (score 0):

Use a file manager. Example using `mc`, navigate into *SQL/tmp*, hit **F2**, ("*Compress the current subdirectory (tar.gz)*"), then **3**, then **Enter**, wait for the archiving, go up a level, (note the new file *SQL/tmp.tar.gz* file), use **F8** to delete *tmp* folder.

(`mc` will compress any files and directories beginning with '**.**' as well.)